# How to clear std::ostream

Tags: c++

How do we clear or empty a std::ostream object?

The examples I have found here are for stringstream;

```
stringstream m;
m.str("");
```

Obviously that does not work with ostream.

EDIT: as asked, for usage:

I use the ostream object in a simple Stopwatch. To trace the time of slow  functions.
With the time the stream object is getting bigger and bigger, and the app goes unresponsive. So here I am trying to clear the ostream object. Preferable in the constructor of CStopUhr.

```
static tstringstream fout;                         // fout to stringstream
//static tofstream fout(_T("SpooferTimeTrace.log); // fout to file 
static std::wostream fout(std::wcout.rdbuf());     // fout to cout

class CStopUhr
{
public:
    CStopUhr(tostream& os, LPCTSTR txt = _T(" Time: ")) 
     :_os(os) 
      { _os.clear(); _txt = txt; _dwStart = GetTickCount(); }
    ~CStopUhr()         
      { _os << _txt << (GetTickCount()-_dwStart) << _T("ms ") << std::endl; }
private:
    DWORD _dwStart;
    tostream& _os;
    tstring  _txt;
};
```

usage:

```
 void testfunction()
 {
    CStopUhr suhr(fout, CString(__FUNCTION__);
    :
    ;
}
```

Comment: what would it mean to empty an `ostream`? Are you sure you don't mean an `istream` (like `std::cin`)?

Comment: What do you think empty ostream looks like?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but doesn't `flush()` flush out anything remaining in the output stream effectively clearing it?

Comment: Maybe tell us what you are trying to do so we can better understand what you mean?

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah but that doesn't line up clearly with what OP has for comparison with `stringstream`

Comment: Best thing to do is to not put the unwanted data in the stream in the first place. By the time you go to remove the unwanted data, all or some of it may have been flushed to the underlying media and out of your reach.

Comment: I have the code added, what I am trying.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see a good reason for you to do that, but maybe you can interfere directly with the underlying `std::streambuf` object, to bump the *put* pointer until there are no more outstanding characters in the buffer?